# What is a better way to create a related table whenever I create a new record of Model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a simple messaging "thread" application like that found in Facebook inbox.

I have two Models:  Message and UserHasMessage.

When a new Message is created, there's a sender and a receiver.  What I do is create two records in UserHasMessage that look like this:

```
 | user_id |  message_id  |  is_sender  |
 |sender_id|  message_id  |    1        |
 |receiver_id| message_id |    0        |
```

I am trying to do it this way, but don't think it looks right:

```
16   def create
 17     @message = Message.new(params[:message])
 18     if @message.save
 19       @user_has_message = UserHasMessage.new
 20       @user_has_message.user_id = params[:sender_id]
 21       @user_has_message.message_id = @message.id
 22       @user_has_message.is_sender = 1
 23       @user_has_message.save
 24       
 25       @user_has_message = UserHasMessage.new
 26       @user_has_message.user_id = params[:receiver_id]
 27       @user_has_message.message_id = @message.id
 28       @user_has_message.is_sender = 0
 29       @user_has_message.save
 30       
 31       flash[:notice] = "Successfully created message."
 32       redirect_to @message
```

BTW:  both params[:receiver_id] and params[:sender_id] are hidden_fields passed from the view/_form ... so I'm not sure how it flows down into create...

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you have here looks fine, but there are some options to clean it up.

Most likely you'll never want to create a message without a sender and receiver? In that case, you could overload the new function on message to take all parameters, like:

```
@message = Message.new(params[:message], params[:sender_id], params[:receiver_id])
```

And then create a before_save validator that checks the validity of the IDs and creates the association records.

If you don't want to override the new function, you could also create functions on the message to accept sender_id and receiver_id, like

```
@message = Message.new()
@message.sender_id = params[:sender_id]
```

And again use before_save to validate and create records.

Finally, another option is to use some combination of the :has_many, :has_one, :belongs_to or :has_many_through model associations to handle everything for you. Especially powerful when you use named_scopes.

Comment: how do I do the latter suggestion.  Does the first suggestion work even though there is no attribute for sender_id or receiver_id on the message itself (this has to be stored in the association UserHasMessages.

Comment: You can define new methods and attributes on your model, and use those methods to do things other than store fields directly in the database. By declaring "def sender_id=(myid)" you can then call that function as described above. For the latter case, a tutorial on model associations is available here.http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html